# what does to oneself mean in some sentence?

Tags: american-english, british-english

I just found a part sentence saying
"`Attractive and affectionate to oneself`"?

Does that mean your attractive to yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably means that you are `narcissistic` or `conceited`

> [narcissistic (adj)](http://www.wordwebonline.com/en/NARCISSISTIC) - Characteristic of those having an inflated idea of their own importance. 
>   [conceited (adj)](http://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=conceited) - Characteristic of false pride; having an exaggerated sense of self-importance

If you found this in some horoscope, as it happens most of the times, that's fine. It shows the *character* of the people with that zodiac sign **in general**. Don't take too much pain. It should not be a heartfelt comment.

Comment: Cool thanks. Its alright. Its fun sometimes to read some horoscope.